# How can I skip middleware in my Rspec request specs?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, middleware

I'm writing some pretty standard Rspec request specs for a Rails app.

```
describe "show" do
  it "should respond successfully when given an id that exists" do
    @badger = FactoryGirl.create(:badger)
    get "/badgers/#{@badger.id}"
    response.should be_ok
  end
end
```

However, we've just added a middleware component for a single sign-on system, so the response comes back as a redirect - "please sign in."

For the purposes of these tests, **how can I leave the middleware out of the chain?** (It has its own tests elsewhere.)

Answer (score 6):

In your `config/environments/test.rb` you can delete this middleware:

```
config.middleware.delete YourMiddleware::Goes::Here
```

Comment: I'd like to be able to do this for a single spec. can this be done for a single spec in a before block for example?

Comment: @shigazaru Not as far as I know. The middleware stack is frozen after initialization, and therefore cannot be modified.